# Separating jetty and application log files

Tags: jetty, slf4j, java.util.logging

I am using slf4j with Java Util Logging, and my application logs are directed through Jetty.

1. How can I get separate output of Jetty startup logs and my application logs. Right now, they are both logged into the same file under `jetty/logs`.
2. How can I control the Jetty startup log format? 
   e.g. I want to change the date format from default "2012-09-13 14:55:36.178:INFO..." to "Sept 13, 2012 14:55:36.178:INFO..." in Jetty logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this page for inspiration:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Sifting_Logs_with_Logback

Long story short, once you have the slf4j-api in the mix then jetty turns logging over to it so you are able to configure whatever you want via slf4j configuration mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. My application uses JUL exhaustively and for some reasons I wanted to avoid moving away from Java Util Logging (say into Logback). Is there a way I can achieve this using JUL? Thanks again!

Comment: once you are in slf4j lands, just use the bridge for it to jul and you should be fine, i think the example uses logback because it was simply easier to use. https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-and-jul-example